# Is it possible to access Unity variables in xcode project?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, unity-game-engine

We have xcode project builded by unity and we have some custom cocoa code there (it's ad networks SDKs actually).

We're going to integrate in-app purchase feature allowing user to hide banners from the app.

How could we set some flag (variable or anything) in Unity to use in the xcode cocoa code?

During the startup, we want to check if such flag was enabled and show the banners only if the flag was set to false.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are probably managaing the plugins from Unity, then just have Unity call in to your Cocoa code to set/reset the flag.

Refer to [Unity Plugins Documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Plugins.html).